# Sorting array by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, rerender

```
export const allFeed = {  feeds: [
{
  id: "1",
  title:
    "Shang- Chi Stays On Record pace With Nearly $35.8 Million In Second Weekend",
  details: [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse minima ex rem quis similique eum ratione quaerat, voluptas molestias ut repudiandae delectus voluptates. Eius esse at tenetur ab accusamus excepturi?",
  ],
  img: "*",
  upvote: "3250",
  downvote: "2250",
  reviews: "5414",
  date: "19-07-2022",
},
{
  id: "2",
  title:
    "Daniel Craig: post your question for actor ahead of his final Bond film",
  details: [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse minima ex rem quis similique eum ratione quaerat, voluptas molestias ut repudiandae delectus voluptates. Eius esse at tenetur ab accusamus excepturi?",
  ],
  img: "*",
  upvote: "2050",
  downvote: "1350",
  reviews: "2253",
  date: "18-07-2019",
},.................



    export default function Feed({ feeds }) {
  const [allFeeds, setAllFeeds] = useState([]);

  const sortArray = (date) => {
    const allDates = {
      date: allFeeds.date,
    };
    const sortProp = allDates[date];
    const sorted = [...allFeeds].sort((a, b) => b[sortProp] - a[sortProp]);
    console.log(sorted);
    setAllFeeds(sorted);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllFeeds(feeds);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="up-left">
        <div>
          <h3>Popular</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 onClick={sortArray}>Recents</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      {allFeeds.map((feed) => (
        <div key={feed.id} className="card">
          <div>
            <p className="feed-title">{feed.title.substring(0, 200)}...</p>
            <div className="card-element">
              <p className="votes">
               .........................
```

[sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8exna.jpg)

Hello everyone. I want it to be sorted by date and rerender when clicking Recent. But I just couldn't. When I console.log I see the array as unsorted. and when I do console.log(allFeeds.date) or (allFeeds.feeds.date) I get undefined. It feels like I'm missing something very simple but I couldn't figure it out. Where am i missing? Why console.log returns undefined ? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for what you can do - arrange the date format in reverse (yyyy-mm-dd) then remove the `-` you will have a sortable number that you can use to sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

1 convert to an array with JSON.parse() if the values are in JSON ... They not in your case pure array

2 Create a function and compare the dates using **new Date()**

```
  var arr = [{id: 1, date: Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM}, {id: 2, date: Mar 8 2012 
                08:00:00 AM}];
 
 sortByDate(arr) {
      arr.sort(function(a,b){
      return Number(new Date(a.readableDate)) - Number(newDate(b.readableDate));
      });

return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's get to the error. First things first, the reason why you are getting `undefined` is you are having `allFeeds` object with feeds as an array. When you `console.log(allFeeds.date)` there is no key-value pair  `date` in your `allFeeds` object, so it gives you `undefined` and when you do `console.log(allFeeds.feeds.date)` here you should use `console.log(allFeeds.feeds[0].date)` because `allFeeds.feeds` is an array.

To solve your problem, you can use the below solution.

```
a.sort((x,y)=>{return new Date(x.date.split("-").reverse().join("-")).getTime() - new Date(y.date.split("-").reverse().join("-")).getTime()})
```

We are doing this because the `Date(dateString)` recieves `dateString` in format `yyyy-mm-dd` and you are having date in `dd-mm-yyyy` which is not acceptable, also we are converting it to `Date` object because as a string `dd-mm-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` does not make much sense, after converting it to the Date object we can use its methods to use the data better.

Comment: Thank you very much, the sort part has been corrected.  So how can I render this sort array on the page by click?

Comment: Is it not rendering after click?

Comment: no doesnt work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Amoos",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum dolor"
    ],
    img: "*",
    upvote: "3250",
    downvote: "2250",
    reviews: "5414",
    date: "2022-07-19"
  },
  { id: "2", date: "1990-12-01" },
  { id: "3", date: "2020-12-15" },
  { id: "4", date: "2007-12-12" }
];

function sortByDateFunc( d1, d2) {
  if (d1.date < d2.date) { return 1; }
  if (d1.date > d2.date) { return -1; }
  return 0;
}

const sortedData = arr.sort(sortByDateFunc);

console.log( sortedData );
```